# Memory leaks redundant messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks

I have a C++ application developed on Visual Studio 2008
On the following code I get a memory leaks like:

f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(141) : {8386} normal block at 0x11BF9DB0, 25 bytes long.
 Data: < 3C 4E 4B 55 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

I have tried many versions, and sure that there is no memory leak here.
Is it a defect in CString?
How can I by-pass this?

```
void fff(CString &s1,CString &s2)
{
    int  nSize =100;
    TCHAR *xx = new TCHAR[100];
    ::GetEnvironmentVariable( s1, xx, nSize );
    CString sss(xx);
    s2 = sss;
    delete[] xx;
}
```

I also get many such leaks on a freshly created MFC application

Comment: Please present your code.

Comment: How can whe help if there is no code?

Comment: We're talking about millions of lines here...

Comment: The point is that this is something to do with MFC - and not specific to my code.

Comment: When you install Visual Studio, there is an option to install runtime source code also.  This includes the MFC source code so you can see what strcore.cpp is doing.

Comment: If you are using xx in local scope, then create it on stack. TCHAR xx[100]; and Use ::GetEnvironmentVariable( s1, xx, sizeof(xx)/sizeof(TCHAR) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try Visual Leak Detector for Visual C++ 2008/2010/2012.

https://vld.codeplex.com/

It will give you the exact location where memory leaks.

Comment: Does it give a stack back trace of the leak?  They already know it comes from strcore.cpp.